# ldap_set_option not setting timeout option

Tags: php, ldap, timeout, settings

I'm using `ldap_connect` to work with an LDAP server from an PHP application, which works fine.
Now I need to set timeouts, so that an request will be canceled if it runs to long.
For this I set the following options with the following lines of code:

```
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldap['host'], $ldap['port'])
            or myExClass::throwException("unable to connect");
echo LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT;
ldap_set_option ($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT,1);
ldap_set_option ($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT,1);
echo LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT;
```

The `echo` are inserted for debugging. In this example I found out, that the option `LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT` is unchanged 4. Before and after `ldap_set_option`.

Why that option is not changed? 
What could be the reason?
By the way: the return code of `ldap_set_option`is 1 in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT` is a flag used to tell [`ldap_set_option()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-set-option.php) which option to set—its value should never change. The `1` in `ldap_set_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT, 1);` is the value you're setting for `LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT`.

Since your calls to `ldap_set_option` are returning `TRUE` it sounds like they're working correctly. You can verify your setting with [`ldap_get_option()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-get-option.php):

```
if( ldap_get_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT, $retVal) ) {
    echo $retVal;
} else {
    echo "Uh oh. Couldn't retrieve value for LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT.";
}
```

Comment: Oh sorry, my mistake. I should use `ldap_get_option($ldapconn, LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT, $retVal)` to get the current value of this specific option, instead of `echo LDAP_OPT_TIMELIMIT;` where I only get the internal "number" of this option. So in this case, the option is set correct, but long running requests are still not canceled. :-(

Comment: okay - i found the reason: the ldap_search has its own timeout parameter, which overwrites the ldap_connect option.